# INMO 2021: A convex quadrilateral with lots of nonstandard angles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

From [INMO 2021](https://secure.hbcse.tifr.res.in/inmo/instructions.php) (held 7 March):

> In a convex quadrilateral ABCD, $\angle ABD = 30^{\circ}$, $\angle BCA = 75^{\circ}$, $\angle ACD = 25^{\circ}$ and $CD = CB$. Extend $CB$ to meet the circumcircle of triangle $DAC$ at $E$. Prove that $CE = BD$.

Lots of angle information makes it suitable for a trigonometric attack. And I know a solution using trigonometry.

Any other approaches? Especially pure geometry proofs will be surprising to me here.

Comment: *"I know a solution using trigonometry."* ... Please include the solution as part of your question, to help people avoid wasting time duplicating the effort or explaining details you already understand, and to provide a potential launching point for an alternative solution. (Besides, it's impossible to tell what counts as an "other approach" if you don't describe the one you know.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select a point $O$ on $AB$ such that $BC=OC$ (it also follows that $OC=CD$).

Via angle chase, observe that $\bigtriangleup OCD$ is equilateral.

Via angle chase, observe that $\bigtriangleup AOC$ is isosceles, hence O is the circumcenter of $\bigtriangleup ADC$.

Finally, note that $\triangle EOC  \cong \triangle BCD$, hence $EC=BD$.

---

As pointed out by @cosmo5 , $O$ must lie between $A$ and $B$ due to angles given in the problem.

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: @DRSKMOBINULHAQUE Thank you :)

Comment: Gorgeous! I will cherish it. Can you tell me your thought process? How did you locate the center of the circle as a point on AB with the property OC=BC?

Comment: @Isomorphism To be honest, I have used GeoGebra to draw the figure. Since this was an olympiad problem I suspected there might be an elegant approach to it. After marking the center of the circle I noticed that we can construct the equilateral triangle $\bigtriangleup OCD$, which lead to $OC=OD=OA$. Though, it is a common theme to construct isosceles and equilateral triangles, hoping that they will lead to a clue.

Comment: I see. "look for equilateral/isosceles triangles" is the idea. Thanks!

Comment: @dodoturkoz This is one beautiful synthetic solution, let me add a diagram to your post (it invites more people to read your solution).

Comment: @MathMinded Excellent idea. Please add this figure.